# DNS problem - dig resolves but curl cannot connect to host

Tags: apache, dns, centos, iptables, rackspace

I have recently created a Rackspace cloud server instance using CentOS 5.5.  I have used yum to install the "Web Server" group (it includes Apache, etc.), added www.booztrakr.com as the ServerName in httpd.conf, made sure iptables allows on port 80.  I had registered this domain with Go-Daddy and changed their name servers to the Rackspace name servers on their site.  I added "A" and CNAME records to the Rackspace name servers. httpd has been started.  When I use curl on the server I can get the Apache landing page. When I dig www.booztrakr.com from a remote machine(over the internet) the answer section returns:

www.booztrakr.com.  300 IN  CNAME   booztrakr.com.

booztrakr.com.      300 IN  A   184.106.216.156
When I try a browser or curl, it can't connect:

curl -G www.booztrakr.com

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

I know this has got to be pretty basic and config related but I'll be dammed if I can see it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you take away the very information that anybody else might need to help diagnose this?

Comment: Does it work if you put the IP address in directly?

Comment: Please provide the domain name at least.

Comment: Very sorry.  The domain is booztrakr.com and ip is 184.106.216.156

Comment: using ip address also can't connect

Answer (score 3):

If dig resolves, this just means the DNS server returns the right values. It will even work if the IP doesn't exists.

If a HTTP connecting to the server fails, this is a configuration problem.

The server responds to ICMP requests, so it's not a routing problem.

> When I use curl on the server I can get the Apache landing page

Your webserver is running, but you just can't reach it from outside. This is the problem. What does `iptables --list` outputs?

Comment: I think this is the entry of interest:
ACCEPT tcp  --  anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:http 
I added the following line to iptables and restarted it:
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Another idea: probably Apache only listens on the loopback interface